# Gistbox group not working

Tags: gist

I'm having trouble using the new functionality gistbox group. If I try to copy any gistbox from my personal library, it seems all good but nothing changes in group's library.

Has anyone the same problem?

Comment: Yes, I have same problem, did you ever resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had been facing the same problem. Here are the details of the problems and how I finally managed to resolve it:

I initially had a gist in my personal library which I shared to a group (no problems yet). Now, I had to make a major update to the gist where I needed to add a number of new files. As I made the update to my gist in my personal library, they do not reflect on the gist in the group, as it creates a copy. So I now had to delete the gist in the group and re-add it from my library.

However, this is where I was facing the problem that you have been facing. It seems all good and gives a confirmation message in my library saying the gist has been copied, but it does not reflect on the group. I tried a number of things, and **finally, what worked is editing the description of the gist before adding it to the group.**